# how do I turn on audit log in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I am using datastax community edition of Cassandra 2.1.  Is there a way I can look at the read/write requests (and the payload sizes) made by the clients?

Answer (score 1):

You can use query tracing to see a full query at request time, and you can see a sample of queries in the system_traces keyspace. [0]

To trace a cqlsh query, start with:

cqlsh> TRACING ON;

then run your query. Some drivers, such as the java driver, support tracing. [1] As far as exact size of the payload, I don't think tracing shows this, but you might include something in your application to log that info.

[0] http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/advanced-request-tracing-in-cassandra-1-2

[1] http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/2.1/java-driver/tracing_t.html